# Electromagnetism for finite element simulations

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations

I want to learn about electromagnetism, as I will need to run (time dependent) finite element simulations regarding electrical motors for my job. I only had one course in EM a long time ago, and I can safely say that I forgot almost everything.

Therefore I'd need a book to start again, with an orientation to numerical applications (FEM simulations). As for me I am an applied mathematician and feel comfortable around calculus and numerics.

It would be good if the reference was self-contained, beginner friendly and concise.

Comment: Sorry, I have no information regarding your question.

One difficulty in simulating electromagnetism is the existence of vacuum (space, void); it is a kind of electromagnetic material and the shape of vacuum is often very complicated. To make a FE mesh model with such space is often a hard work.
In the rotating motor, there is a thin gap between the rotor and the stator. And the shape of the gap changes as the rotation progresses. Therefore, the FEM mesh has to be changed as the rotation progresses. This aspect is very difficult to solve numerically.